# Robotium in C# project

Tags: c#, android, .net, automated-tests, robotium

I am looking for a mobile automated testing tool and have found `robotium`.  Will it work with C# android app?  Can I add the robotium jar file to a .Net project?

Answer (score 0):

While it is likely that, with some amount of work, Robotium could be made to work with Xamarin.Android, it is an amount of relatively complicated work that the Robotium project is unlikely to do. (the killer item probably being good IDE integration)

However, it appears that Xamarin has acquired a testing framework for mobile applications called [Calabash](http://calaba.sh/). They have devoted a page to explaining it on their main site: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/introduction-to-calabash/. My instinct here (without having tried it) would be to try and make it work, as it is pretty likely that Calabash will be supported by Xamarin in the future.